# What's the right way of observing interpolated values of an animated property of a SwiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to observe the interpolated value of `rotation` in the below example. How does one achieve that? I only seem to be able to get the end value.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiqvH.gif)

```
struct ExampleView: View {

    @State var rotation = Angle.zero

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.blue)
            Text("Example")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .rotation3DEffect(rotation, axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                rotation = Angle(degrees: rotation.degrees + 60)
            }
        }.onChange(of: rotation) { newValue in
            // Only prints the end value
            print(newValue.degrees)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried both with implicit animation and explicit animations but both give me the same output. Same applies to `animatedData` of the `Angle` instance `rotation` here.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to know the interpolated values?

Comment: When I have a conditional as in `rotation.degrees < 90` that condition is not in sync with the animation as the rotation value is set to its `to` value immediately before the animation finishes. Then the side effect happens sooner than it should. If I can observe the interpolated value then the timing will match. Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but... If you add 60 degrees to the angle, there is no interpolated value - there is a step increase from 0 to 60 to 120 to 180. You should increase the angle of 1 degree 60 times.

Comment: @DenizEroglu - you may want to look at `TimelineView` ... check the  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview) first. Quick search comes up with this article that looks promising https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part4/

Comment: Thanks for the comments! 

HunterLion, SwiftUI does compute the interpolation (as far as I understand) for performing the animation. So increasing the degree 1 at a time would work however it wouldn't be the ideal solution when the animation engine already is calculating the data. 

Thanks DonMag, will look into it!